# related objects in steps with cucumber/pickle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, bdd, pickle

it would be great if somebody could help me with the cucumber/pickle syntax on creating
related objects and assert them.
How can I get references in my cucumber syntax...

Something Like

For example: creating a blog post with a certain title with 3 comments
And then assert this post and the related comments...

Is this with object builder by pickle possible or do I have to write these steps manually
and how do I reference the value from master in detail?

I am looking especially for reffering Object in different steps and inserting master with its details in one batch with pickle (without defining the step manually) and then asserting it....
I should have 1 blogpost with 3 comments...

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following screen-casts:

1. http://railscasts.com/episodes/155-beginning-with-cucumber
2. http://railscasts.com/episodes/159-more-on-cucumber
3. http://railscasts.com/episodes/186-pickle-with-cucumber

These put me well on my way to cucumber and pickle goodness

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the links I watched them before... they are great. I am looking especially for reffering Object in different steps and inserting master with its details in one batch with pickle (without defining the step manually)